# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.1-2-13.min.js:1

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular jS and while.I am using node server to deploy my application locally.Bit facing this error in chrome browser.

PFB my code

Demo.html

```
<html ng-app="Demo">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.1-2-13.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route.1-2-13.min.js">         </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="DemoController">

USA<input type='radio' name='txt1' ng-model="value" ng-         change="changeValue(value)" value="USA"> Non-USA<input type='radio'   name='txt1' ng-model="value" ng-change="changeValue(value)" value="NUSA">

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options='option.name for option in optionValues'>
</select>
<input type='text' name='txt1' ng-model='txtValue'/>
<input type='button' name='b1' ng-click='takeValue(txtValue)'/>
<a href="#/about">routing</a>
<div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var demo = angular.module( "Demo", ['ngRoute'] );

demo.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function        ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
// Pages
.when("/about", {templateUrl:      "/Users/smundhe/Desktop/NewProject/Demo2.html",controller:   "Demo2Controller"})
// else 404
.otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html",controller:  "PageCtrl"});
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);

demo.controller(
        "DemoController",
        function( $scope ) { 

            $scope.optionValues=[{name:'1'},{name:'2'},{name:'3'},  {name:'4'}];
            $scope.takeValue = function(txtValue){
                alert(txtValue);

            }
            $scope.changeValue=function(value){
                alert(value);
                if(value=="USA"){
                    $scope.optionValues=[{name:'1'},{name:'2'}, {name:'3'},{name:'4'}];
                }
                else if(value=="NUSA"){
                    $scope.optionValues=[{name:'A'},{name:'B'},   {name:'C'},{name:'D'}];
                }
            }

        });

demo.controller(
        "Demo2Controller",
        function( $scope ) { 

            $scope.optionValues=[{name:'1'},{name:'2'},{name:'3'},{name:'4'}];

            alert('hiii');
        });
</script>
```

server.js

```
// set our port
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var port = 3000; 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.get('/*', function(req,res)
{
console.log('sending file: ' + req.url);
res.sendfile(__dirname  + '/Demo.html');
});
app.listen(port);
```

Can some one help me on this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: check this out if its the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res)
{
  console.log('sending file: ' + req.url);
  res.sendfile(__dirname  + '/Demo.html');
});
```

This is basically saying that for any incoming GET request, always send back `Demo.html`. As a result, when your page's `<script>` tag requests the `angular.min.js`, it is given `Demo.html`, which the browser then tries to run as a javascript file, throwing the "unexpected `<`" error.

Instead, what you should do is something like the following:

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname, {'index': ['Demo.html']}))
```

This will essentially serve whatever file is requested, and if no file is requested (i.e. `/`, then will return `Demo.html`).

**Note** you will need to `npm install --save serve-static`.

See [the serve-static docs](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) for more info.