# How to solve SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I take from here : http://jsfiddle.net/59p19q7z/3/

I try in localhost like this : http://pastebin.com/5NixFQ8S

in console exist error like this :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: going to need to see the code before it, that's where the error would be.

Comment: I dont see any syntax error in console though

Comment: where is that error coming from in the demo no error can be seen in console

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak, in jsfiddle no error, but I try in localhost, there exist error

Comment: @guradio, You try in your localhost. There exist error

Comment: @mosestoh: Is there anything else in your markup before the select?

Comment: @SandeepNayak, No. The code is the same as jsfiddle

Comment: @Hazonko, I had see the code. But I'm still have not found a solution

Comment: Isn't it related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got

Comment: @A.Wolff, I had see it. But, I'm still confused to implement in my case

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**