# Using Angular 1.5 Component router with Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm developing an Express application, I want to catch all routes and redirect users to `/public/app/index.html`:

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('/public/app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

But when I run the server, this displays on the screen:

```
================================================== -->
```

With these errors on console:

```
jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
hover.zoom.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
hover.zoom.conf.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
allJS.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you inspected it with a debugging tool like Chrome Developer Tools? If I had to guess, I'd say your HTML page has the wrong URLs for those scripts and it's returning errors in the form of HTML (which blows up when being interpreted as JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got)

What's happening is you're getting `index.html` for every single `GET` request your app is making.

You can get around this by checking if a filename is being requested in your `routes` file.

NOTE: In this example. I used the [app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path) module to get path for specific files

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
...
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    var filename = req.originalUrl;
    //if it has a dot in its name return the original file
    if (/(\.)/g.test(req.originalUrl)){
        res.sendfile(appRoot + '/public/' + filename);
    }
```

Comment: In Chrome, open the developer tools (ctrl+shift+i) and go to the Network tab. Then reload your page. You should see requests for "jquery.min.js", "hover.zoom.js", etc. Click one of those, click the "Response" tab on the right, and I bet you see some HTML error response.

Comment: Yes, you are right. all css will be loaded with this address `/css/filename.cs`. but the only problem is this file `/min/allJS.min.js`

Comment: And what do you see in the Network inspector for `/min/allJS.min.js`?