# When scaffolding generator-angular-express app on windows, I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, yeoman

Steps to reproduce:
Installed generator-angular-express
Scaffolded the generic application
Run the default 'grunt' task
Open browser to localhost:9999

When doing so I recieve a blank page, and when inspecting the page with Chrome dev tools, I notice 3 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' errors. I cant seem to find the cause of this, scaffolding the same app worked fine in OSX, but on Windows via Cygwin terminal or Webstorm, I keep running into this issue.

Express Version:

$ express --version
4.13.4

Node Version:

$ node --version
v4.4.7

Below is my express file:

```
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var express = require('express');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = module.exports = express();

var globalConfig = {
    minify: process.env.MINIFY == 'yes' ? true : false,
    environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT || 'local'
};

var rootPath = path.dirname(__dirname);
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 9999);

app.set('views', path.join(rootPath, 'server'));
app.engine('html', cons.handlebars);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

if(globalConfig.environment == 'local') {
    app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
}

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var config = configFromReq(req);
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url);
    var splittedPath = parsedUrl.pathname.split(path.sep);

    if(splittedPath[1]) {
        var fileExtension = getFileExtension(parsedUrl.pathname);
        if(fileExtension == 'js' || fileExtension == 'css') {
            addPathPrefix(splittedPath, getMinPrefix(config));
        }
    }

    parsedUrl.pathname = splittedPath.join(path.sep);
    req.url = url.format(parsedUrl);

    req.config = config;
    next();
});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(rootPath, 'app')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    renderIndex(req.config, res);
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});

function renderIndex(config, res) {
    res.render(getMinPrefix(config) + '/views/index');
}

function configFromReq(req) {
    var config = {};
    config.minify = req.cookies.minify == 'true' ? true : false;
    return config;
}

function getMinPrefix(conf) {
    return conf.minify || globalConfig.minify ? 'minified' : 'unminified';
}

function addPathPrefix(filePath, prefix) {
    filePath.splice(1, 0, prefix);
}

function getFileExtension(filePath) {
    return filePath.split('.').pop();
}
```

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got/30249374#30249374

Comment: Could you provide more details? Do a grunt --verbose as well as copy the entire error from chrome console.

Comment: (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: The grunt build appears to work fine, I could add the verbose build but nothing fails, it seems to be only on the built webapp were I see the failure in devtools