# Got Error: Module 'myApp' is not available! using AngularJS 1.6.1, Node.js and Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm a begginer in angularJS, Node and Express and am at the very beginning of a tutorial to code a very simple To-do List using angularJS, Node and Express.
I am using Node.js v7.9.0, Express.js v4.15.2, and AngularJS v1.6.1.
I am using nodemon to run my server.js.

I keep getting 3 errors and I don't understand why:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[En savoir plus]  app.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[En savoir plus]  route.js:1
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
minErr/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:68:12
module/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:2183:17
ensure@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:2107:38
module@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:2181:14
loadModules/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4736:22
forEach@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:357:11
loadModules@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4720:5
createInjector@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4642:19
doBootstrap@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1838:20
bootstrap@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1859:12
angularInit@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1744:5
@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:32977:5
trigger@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:3314:5
```

This is my files path :

```
-todolist
--node_modules
--public
---views
----home.hmtl
---app.js
---index.html
---route.js
--package.json
--server.js
```

My server.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser= require('body-parser');
var method = require('method-override');

//application
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html', {root : __dirname});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My app.js :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['appRoutes']);
```

My route.js :

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
                  }
            )
});
```

My index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="route.js"></script>
        <title>Une To-Do Liste</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the home.html contains a simple test, but fails to display :

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

For the moment the website only display the string 'To-do List' from my index.html.
Why do I get 2 syntax errors from my app.js and route.js ? And why is my 'myApp' module not defined ?

Answer (score 1):

My app.js :

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

My route.js :

```
 angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($routeProvider){
       $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
                      }
                )
    });
    //with test controller
     angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('TestCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
           $scope.it = 'works';
        }]);
```

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <script src="route.js"></script>
            <title>Une To-Do Liste</title>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
           <div ng-controller="TestCtrl"> 
              <h1>To-do List</h1>
             it {{it}}
          </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work... displays {{it}} instead of 'works'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by missing inclusion of ngRoute module. Please take look at [AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr)

Comment: I don't understand, i am including the appRoutes in my app.js with  "angular.module('myApp', ['appRoutes']);", am I not ?

Comment: You need Define module 

angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sequence of file. As you are injecting `appRoutes` in the `myApp` it should be defined.

```
<script src="route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

---

Define all required modules in *app.js*

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute']); //Define module
angular.module('myApp', ['appRoutes']);
```

In *route.js*, retrieve defined `appRoutes` and add config section

```
angular.module('appRoutes')
    .config(function($routeProvider){
       $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
                      }
                )
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I keep geting the 2 syntax errors and the 3rd error is still telling me that the module 'myApp' is not available

Comment: @ElyaBernard, Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got