# load static file in a template that extends other template - Django javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

I want to load a javascript file in the template that extends my base_generic template. I am using generic listView to render the template.

Since I can not use "{% url %}" tamplate tag inside of "{% block %}" tag  I hardcoded the link as follows:

```
<script src="static/js/search.js">
```

Unfortunately the file does not work and I get a a message that: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' "

I guess it is because my view tries to render the template as html (am I right?) - my assumption is based on this post: [SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got)

So my question is: how can I load a static file in the template that extends another template.

EDIT:

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}


  {% block content %}


  {% if search_flag %}
  SEARCHFLAG ON
  {% else %}

  <h2 class="myh"> Książki: </h2>

  {% if book_list %}
  <script>
  var lista=[];
  {% for book in book_list %}
  var title="{{book.title}}";
  var authors=[];
  {% for author in book.author.all %};

    var aut="{{author.last_name}}";


    authors.push(aut);

  {% endfor %}

  var authorsStr=authors.join('; ');

  var book=[title, authorsStr]
  lista.push(book);

  {% endfor %}
  console.log("created list of books and authors - name: lista")
  </script>

  {% else %}

  <p>W katalogu nie ma książek</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}


  <script src="static/js/search.js">
  </script>


  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you post the code of the template?? from top to bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `{% url %}` tag to get path to you static file, just write this on the top of your template file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

After that, you can get access to your static files by folowing constructions:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/search.js' %}">
```

Read more in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/).

If you want to extend the base template, you have to add block script and extend it to your templates

base.html:

```
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/search.js' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: You forgot `scripts` in the block name =)

Comment: Yes - I used the wrong template tag. I mark it as an answer, thanks a lot. However I still do not know what was the problem with the hardcoded version of the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{% url "" %}` in a `block`. To use `static` make sure to include `{% load static %}` directly after the `extends` template tag when you need it. Then you can:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/search.js' %}">
```