# Client side routing with react-router and expressJS only works one level deep

Tags: reactjs, express, web, webpack, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router to enable client side routing, but I can only get the routing to behave as expected at one level deep past "/". (i.e. **localhost:8080/** works, **localhost:8080/{id}** works, but **localhost:8080/vote/{id}** does not)

Additionally, I am trying to develop locally using webpack-dev-server, and deploy to heroku using webpack -p and an expressjs server. My express server is set to have all routes default to index.html.

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/index.html'));
});
```

When using npm start (express server) and I try to navigate to localhost:8080/vote/{id} the console says: *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'* meaning I have a situation like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got). However, when using webpack-dev-server, I get a different error in the console that says: *Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:8080/vote/bundle.js”.* I believe what I'm seeing is two different outputs for the same core problem, the difference being my environment or differences in how express/webpack-dev-server are serving up the content.

Here is my full expressJS server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app = express();
// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')));

// send the user to index html page inspite of the url
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("server started on port " + port);
```

Here are the relevant parts of my webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
```

And here is my App.js with relevant routes (Home, RealtimeView, PollVote being custom React components):

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/:id" component={RealtimeView} />
                    <Route exact path="/vote/:id" component={PollVote}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

With this configuration, I can reliably get **localhost:8080/** to work and **localhost:8080/{whatever}** to work but **localhost:8080/vote/{id}** or any route more complicated than localhost:8080/{something} fails with the errors I mentioned earlier depending on if I'm using webpack-dev-server or my expressjs server.

FWIW I'm relatively new to webdev (my experience so far is that it's a cluster-fck) and I can't go with a totally isomorphic app because my back-end is in java/spring and I'm not re-writing my whole back-end. I found [this post to be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually?rq=1) but it doesnt solve my problem. Please help this is making me crazy.

Comment: Try re-ordering your routes. Put `/:id` after `/vote/:id`. It may be treating `vote` as an id and stopping there instead of considering the routes that come after. Also look into `<Switch/>` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Comment: @wdm I've tried both reordering the routes and using a Switch component as per the docs with the same issue. Thanks for the suggestion anyway I appreciate the help

Comment: Did you try to remove `devServer.contentBase` attr?

Comment: This route:  `<Route exact path="/:id" component={RealtimeView} />`  will catch all parameters after "/", instead you need to refactor it to something like: `<Route exact path="realtime/:id" component={RealtimeView} />`. In addition, use Eugene's answer below. And, you may also need to add an `output: { publicPath: '/'} }` in your `webpack.config.js`. I also have Webpack Full Stack Boilerplate: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate/tree/fullstack that you can reference/use.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting fallback file explicitly:

```
historyApiFallback:{
  index: 'index.html'
}
```