# javascript file is not working in vue cli html template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using vue cli to create a multipage web app.
The file structure is like below:

```
- public
   - index.html
   - tables.html
   - us.html
   - guide.html
- src
   - main.js
```

and the main.js is:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

console.log('hello world!');

let appExists = document.querySelector('#app') != undefined;
if(appExists){
  new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
    mounted(){
      console.log('hi!');
    }
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

**What I'm looking for:**

I want main.js file to be loaded into tables.html file.

**What is happening:**

main.js is not working in any file except index.html.

**What I have done:**

As I searched, I realized that vue cli loads the main.js only in index.html and not in any other file. when I try to load the main.js using `<script src="/src/main.js"></script>` in tables.html, I always get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. I tried some solutions like https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages but it didn't change anything at all.

**And the question is:**

What should I do to use main.js in other files?

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got

Comment: @ewong Thanks, but I also read other questions like this one. I think there can be an easier way than dealing with node or express codes, like changing some kind of vue cli configurations or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Everything in vue cli works with the combination of webpack plugins.

The plugin which connects the files together is called "HtmlWebpackPlugin".

First, install the plugin using:

```
npm i html-webpack-plugin
```

Then you can tell this plugin: "Hey I have another page in my project! Please connect main.js to it" by writing the code below in vue.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


    module.exports = {
      configureWebpack: {
          plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              filename: 'tables.html',
              template: './public/tables.html',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              filename:'index.html',
              template: './public/index.html',
            }),
          ]
      }
    }
```

Hope it will help other people who are facing the same issue!