# Deploying app and getting temporary error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, kubernetes

After deploying my create-react-app + express server, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I only get the error for about 2-3 minutes and then the app loads.

Two questions:

1. What causes this? (I've seen this question come up a lot, but not in the case where it resolves itself after a couple minutes and using create-react-app + express
2. How to prevent this from happening?

Also, I'm using Kubernetes + docker for the deployment so the pods roll over when the new app is deployed.

Comment: That sounds like what happens when the UI makes a HTTP request to a server and expects a JSON response, but gets HTML instead. This can happen if the server is returning an error page. In your case it might be a 503 page that goes away once the backend is up and running. Check the Network tab in the browser devtools for failed requests.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got). Did you check your pods logs ? You should be able to find more details on what's actually is going on.